# viewDidAppear for specific views

Tags: ios

I have two ViewControllers, call them A(initial VC) and B. They are connected by a segue. I want to only perform an action when the view B appears, so I added `viewDidAppear` listener. However, even when just A is loaded, B's `viewDidAppear()` is called. Is this normal? If it is, what should I do?

EDIT:

The first VC:

```
- (IBAction)addBtnPressed:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"add Btn pressed");
}

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    ViewController *destVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    destVC.destStation = self.destField.text;
    }
```

These are the outlets that are connected to the button

[image]

Storyboard
[image]

Log:

```
2015-02-06 23:03:35.499 a[47067:2112434] second view did load
2015-02-06 23:03:35.501 a[47067:2112434] first view did load
2015-02-06 23:03:35.586 a[47067:2112434] second view did appear
2015-02-06 23:03:35.588 a[47067:2112434] first view did appear
```

I don't understand why second view did appear is called before than the first

Comment: B's `viewDidAppear` definitely should NOT be called unless you segue to it or it is a child view controller in A.

Comment: It would also help to see some code or what you're doing to find out what's happening.

Comment: @AdamPro13 @LyricalPanda I just added more information. Do you have an idea why B's `viewDidAppear` is called as soon as the app is done loading?

Comment: Also, I have `views` (for background colors) inside each `ViewController` too, but I am not sure if that's the culprit. All the view controllers are connected by NavigationController too.

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` for the second view controller and use the stack trace to figure out where the second view controller is being init'd.